# in c programming i am trying to display the number of times a user enters a certain number ,

Tags: c

For a lottery game I need display the frequency of the numbers entered each time the user enters a new set of numbers on the screen for the numbers 1-42 for example, it might display

number 1 has been selected x times number 7 has been selected x times number 28 has been selected x times etc., this has to be done in a function here is my code please help thanks

```
void numberFrequency(int *nums,int *frequency)

{

int i;
    int j;
    int temp;
    int freq[42]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
                  12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
                  20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,
              28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,
              36,37,38,39,40,41,42};

    for (i=0;i<NUMS;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<FREQUENCY;j++)
        {
            if (*(nums+i)==j+1);
            {
                temp = *(frequency+j);
                temp++;
                *(frequency+j) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<FREQUENCY;j++)
    {
        if (*(frequency+j)>=1)
        {
            printf("\nThe number %d was entered %d times ",j+1,*(frequency+j));
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Good for you! Your question is?

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes a valid input.
This code will print the number of time each number was selected.

```
void numberFrequency(int *nums)
{
    int i;
    int freq[42];

    for(i=0;i<42;i++)
        freq[i] = 0;//init counters to 0;

    for (i=0;i<NUMS;i++)
         freq[nums[i]]++;

    for(i=0;i<42;i++)
       printf("The num:%d entered $d times",i+1,freq[i]);
}
```

Comment: thank you that really helped but it dosent seem to be working properly what am i doing wrong the output if i enter 1,2,3,4,5,6 then 4,5,6,7,8,9, is number 1 entered 0 times number 2 entered 0 times number 3 entered 0 times number 4 entered 0 times number 5 entered 1 times number 6 entered 1 times number 7 entered 1 times number 8 entered 1 times number 9 entered 1 times number 10 entered 1 times any ideas how to fix this cheers :)

Comment: how do you get NUMS array ?
what is inside it ?

Comment: NUMS is a global variable of size 6 (#define NUMS 6) this is the first part of my code #include <stdio.h>
#define NUMS 6 //function to take input from user 
void myNumbers(int *nums){
 
 int i;
 printf ("Please enter your lucky numbers\n");
 
 for (i=0;i<NUMS;i++)//loop through array to take input
 {
  
        scanf("%d",&*(nums+i));
        
     if (*(nums+i) < 1 || *(nums+i) > 42)
     {
    
      printf("The number you entered is out of range\n");
      printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 42\n");
      i--;
     }
     
 }
 
}//end myNumbers function